# Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.annotation.Resource]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Tags: java, spring, exception

When I am trying to initialize my database with `AppConfig` file, I catch this exception.

Here piece of stacktrace :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'appConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'schemaScript': 
Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.annotation.Resource]; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] 
to required type [javax.annotation.Resource]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert 
value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.annotation.Resource]; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type 
[javax.annotation.Resource]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

My `AppConfig` file :

```
@Value("classpath:schema.sql")
private Resource schemaScript;


@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(final DataSource dataSource) {
    final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
    return initializer;
}

private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addScript((org.springframework.core.io.Resource) schemaScript);
    return populator;
}

   @Autowired
Environment environment;

@Bean
DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty(URL));
    driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty(USER));
    driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty(PASSWORD));
    driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty(DRIVER));
    return driverManagerDataSource;
}
```

I called this bean in this way :

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
```

and catch exception.

Comment: You are using the wrong `Resource` class. You are using the annotation whereas you should use the `org.springframework` on.

Comment: @M.Deinum It helped. Thanks a lot!